# Accidentally replaced all files in etc folder, which broke my terminal

Tags: terminal

I stupidly replaced all the files in this folder, as I upgraded to Mavericks and wanted to restore my old terminal settings. In hindsight very silly!
It broke a few things and would not let me undo. Is there any way I can get the default files for this folder `/private/etc/`?

Hoping I don't have to reinstall the whole operating system!
Thanks.

Comment: Reinstalling macOS from the Recovery Partition actually is the way to go.

Comment: This won't delete your files ^

Comment: It's Mavericks… no protection. You can simply copy back the original data [unless you binned it without a backup, in which case, as above - reinstall the OS from Recovery]

Comment: Also, once you've restored /etc, use .bashrc etc in ~ for your configuration, the files in /etc wil sometimesl be overritten with upgrades.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I should clarify - OSX is still running fine, it's just terminal that won't run ( it says [process completed] with no prompt) so I feel like there must be a simpler solution - I am wondering if I can just download the default files from somewhere and replace what is in /etc/ again with these defaults?

Comment: OK, so my main issue now is simply that the password no longer works, if I try to change preferences etc (though login screen still works!)
But if I can get the text within the default file for the `/etc/passwd` file, I think I may be able to replace it and that will fix it...or maybe one of the other files. Let me know if there's a place I can download the defaults!

Comment: There isn't.  If you'd just reinstalled the OS, you'd have been done by now.  Its non-destructive.

Comment: So everything will be identical if I do that @MarcWilson?  I won't I need to reinstall all my applications etc?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to.

Comment: Thanks, all back to normal! Solved.